# How to filter array using NSPredicate such that value of one property is greater than other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an array of objects which two properties X and Y (both `NSString`). I want to filter the array using predicate such that all the filtered objects have X > Y. Currently, I am using:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(X > Y"];
```

My program crashes at this line. What is the correct way of writing this predicate?

Comment: You have unbalanced parenthesis in your predicate string. Is that a typo or the problem?

Comment: A NSString object doesn't "have an X value". The values you use should be properties of the object you're filtering.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, I think he's saying that properties X and Y on his custom class are of type NSString, not that the object that has the properties is an NSString.

When you say X and Y are strings, what do you mean that X should be greater than Y? Are they string representations of numbers? Do you mean X comes before Y in alphabetical order? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Thanks David. You pointed it out right that I was missing a parenthesis and due to unbalance parenthesis, there was a crash at run time. Problem solved.Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X > Y"];
```

or

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(X > Y)"];
```

should work fine, I think you missed an `)`.

Check out Apple's documentation: [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Try `-[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:]`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(MyClass *object, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [object.x compare:object.y] == NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

This is assuming `x` and `y` are strings that you want in alphabetical order. If that's not the case, please edit your question to specify exactly what x > y for strings means.

Comment: +1: I hate predicate formats, it seems like you're programming in another language.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you have?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(X > Y"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(X > Y)"];
```

Because this is missing a ')'
and what are you trying to compare? string.length > string.length? or is it a number @"3" > @"5"?

Here is your [Predicate programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-CJBDBHCB)

Comment: I think this should be a comment.  Oh look, David Ronnqvist already put it as one...